# pyspark container work locally but not when deployed to AWS lambda

Tags: java, docker, hadoop, pyspark, aws-lambda

I have create a pyspark batch pipeline and packed into a docker container. everything works fine locally until I deploy it to run as AWS lambda function.

The error message is as follows:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found**

and trackback is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/task/pipeline.py", line 71, in 
> df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(parquet_output)
> File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1140, in parquet
> self._jwrite.parquet(path)
> File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in **call**
> return_value = get_return_value(
> File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
> return f(*a, **kw)
> File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
> raise Py4JJavaError(
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.parquet.
> : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:461)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:558)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:793)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
> ... 25 more
> END RequestId: fde8d18e-0a38-4242-a919-8f94530a87e4
> REPORT RequestId: fde8d18e-0a38-4242-a919-8f94530a87e4  Duration: 32409.88 ms   Billed Duration: 32410 ms   Memory Size: 5120 MB    Max Memory Used: 472 MB
> RequestId: fde8d18e-0a38-4242-a919-8f94530a87e4 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
> Runtime.ExitError

My question here is:

How come the same container image works locally but not on lambda? My understanding is that if a Docker image runs locally, it should also work when it is deployed to any cloud environment since it is self-contained.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: also I have both hadoop-aws-3.3.2  and aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.289.jar added to PYSPARK_HOME so my pipeline can write parquet file to S3

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use lambda for this? AWS Glue jobs provide full Spark runtime so you could do your processing there.